# Find all the rectangles coordinates in a numpy 2d array ( prioritizing the vertical rectangles)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to figure out a solution for finding all the rectangles in a 2d array.
But in the mean while, I need to get the vertical ones first.
For example:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

The desire output would be

```
[[0, 2, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 3, 2, 4]]
```

Or something like

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]
```

Output should be

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 3, 2, 3], [1, 4, 1, 4]]
```

In other words, if it's a horizontal rectangle of the height of only 1, it is viewed as multiple 11.
I am kind of stuck on the logic which should proceed first, my results prioritize the horizontal ones and have troubles dealing with zeros when encounter a 2*2 or above rectangle.

UPDATE
A rectangle in here means an area composed of 1s in the 2d array. However when something like

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

happens, the output should be

```
[[1, 3, 2, 3], [1, 4, 1, 4]]
```

instead of

```
[[1, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 2, 3]]
```

1*1 counts as a rectangle too

The code I have for now looks like this

```
def solve2(grid):


 output = []
  visited = set()
  for j in range(len(grid[0])):
    for i in range(len(grid)):
      if (i,j) in visited:
        continue
      visited.add((i,j))
      if grid[i][j] == 1:
        s_row, s_col = i, j
        e_row, e_col = i,j

        while e_col < len(grid[0]) and grid[i][e_col]:
          while e_row < len(grid) and grid[e_row][j]:
            e_row += 1
          e_col += 1
          
        
        for x in range(s_row, e_row):
          for y in range(s_col, e_col):
            visited.add((x,y))
        e_row -= 1
        e_col -= 1
        output.append([s_row, s_col, e_row, e_col])
  return output
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "rectangle" in this data? Tell us enough about the semantics of your input and output to be able to understand the question.

Comment: And, more importantly, can you show us what you have tried? SO is for troubleshooting specific problems in code, not a code-writing service.

Comment: I haven't worked out the logic going from your input/output examples, but you could probably use convolution for this. Although this would only create an easy solution for the rectangle with a static size.

Comment: Please explain in words how the output is created from the input? It is unclear now. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Ehsan so for my examples, the output is actually a list of all the rectangles' top left corner's coordinate and the bottom right corner coordinate, sorry I wasn't being clear

Comment: It is still unclear to me. the coordinates of a 2-D array is 2 numbers (rows and columns) but your output for your first example is of shape 3*4.

Comment: Hi @Ehsan the first output indicates 3 rectangles, and for each column represent the coordinates, for example [ top_leftX, top_leftY, bottom_rightX, bottom_rightY ]